# Insert query with null values is throwing exception - mybatis

Tags: oracle, mybatis, spring-mybatis

We are using mybatis to do the database activities. I am facing an issue while inserting data into db.

Problem: I have 10 fields in a table, only one field is notnull which is primary key - other than that all column's can be nullable. **When I am trying to insert only 3 columns it is giving exception with the below query.** Please let me know if there is any solution to solve the below query.

Query:

```
@Insert("insert into defendant (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10)"
        + " values (#{defendantInfo.c1}, #{defendantInfo.c2}, #{defendantInfo.c3}, #{defendantInfo.c4}, #{defendantInfo.c10}, #{defendantInfo.c5}, #{defendantInfo.c6}, #{defendantInfo.c7}, #{defendantInfo.c8}, #{defendantInfo.c9})")
public void insertInToDefendant(DocumentEntryWrapper doc);
```

Exception:`java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: 1111
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getInternalType(OracleStatement.java:3916) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setNullCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4541) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setNull(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4523) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setNull(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1281) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]`

NOTE: What I observed is #{defendantInfo.c10} - here "defendantInfo.c10" is null, so we have to do some check before executing the query. But I am not sure of doing the check.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you tried to insert a value with null parameter. You have to explicitly set the jdbcType of the column which may be null like:

```
{myObject.nullableColumn, jdbcType=VARCHAR}
```